# How to Delete existing duplicate post from WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have at least 9000 posts in my word-press and i want to delete only duplicate post which was created before? so i just want to delete those extra posts which was there in my word-pres. I try to find out if i am get any plug-in related to it but i can't

Is there any plug-in or script there which will help me to do this?

reply will be appreciated!

thank

Comment: Unlikely this is a rather specialized task IMO and writing a plug-in for it would be of little use to others.

Comment: It sounds like you need a MySQL statement for this. Delete all your posts with a date less than your newest posts? without viewing the data, I wouldn't know what was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Darshan may be this will help you.

http://blog.xoogie.net/2009/07/14/auto-delete-duplicate-post/

This plugins for delete duplicate posts in wordpress.

Thanks...

Comment: Its a spam link

Answer (score 3):

you should probably start with restricting [`revisions`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revision_Management)

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 10); // paste in wp-config
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions

I also advice to just delete all current revisions from the database with the following SQL:

```
DELETE a,b,c FROM `wp_posts` a
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'revision';
```

After that make a list of all posts with the same post title:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`post_title` DESC
```

Look for double post titles, post-types etc, and note there ID's
If you have a list of double ID's. use this SQL to delete them:

```
DELETE a,b,c,d,e FROM `wp_posts` a
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
LEFT JOIN `wp_comments` d ON (a.ID = d.comment_post_ID)
LEFT JOIN `wp_commentmeta` e ON (d.ID = e.comment_id)
WHERE a.ID = FOUND_ID; # 1 ID at once
```

**Do make a backup before you start**
I hope this helps